# How to convert Jsonl file data into Binary content in ADF

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to convert the Json file data into Binary format. At the sink, the file data should convert the text data (inside Json file) into Binary data as that's how the end user wants to receive the file.

Is there any way to do this conversion in ADF or in SQL.

Comment: as per my understanding you want to convert json data to binary data is i am correct

Comment: can you add sample input file data??

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this conversion in ADF or in SQL.

AFAIK there is no direct way to transform the json file data and store it again in binary format you can do this by other programing language and SQL.

**In SQL there is an option to convert Json (nvarchar) column to binary**.

1. First take lookup to get the data from json file. as below.
   [image]
2. Then using copy data add this Json data as column value in Table where the column with datatype nvarchar(max).
   [image]
   [image]
3. Then using copy data convert this Json data value in Table to binary format and update in json file.
   [image]
   [image]

**Output:**

[image]